# Animate the Parent <div> when using class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

+More
        
Each block will have an article summary in it.

```
    <div class="contentBlockTwo">
    <span class="moreButton">+More</span>
    <br /> Or new flashes.</div>
```

As you can see I have my "spans" as the same class so I can apply the following jQuery to them:

```
            $('.moreButton').click(function () {

                $('.moreButton').parent().animate({ width: '98%' }, 800);
            });
```

But no matter which of the "span" items I click, ALL of the "Divs" have the animation applied to them.

How can I apply the animation to the parent of the sender/ clicked "span" without giving each "div" an ID?

Thanks

Comment: not entirely sure if this is what you need but, you could try `$(this).parent('div').animate(...)`

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
$('.moreButton').parent().animate({ width: '98%' }, 800);
```

with

```
$(this).parent().animate({ width: '98%' }, 800);
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks alot for very fast reply.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/53TjS/1/

Yeah, I think that does it.

`$(this).parent('div').animate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.moreButton').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({ width: '98%' }, 800);
});
```

You need to use the `this` object otherwise it is re-selecting the parent elements of *all* .moreButton rather than the one you clicked.

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks alot for very fast reply.